# How to align vertically 1 top 2 bottom picture

Tags: html, css

I could center two first images in vertical, but next 2 images must be next to each other and aligned with top too.
here how it looks http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/
should look like this: http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/img/example.jpg

tried float:left but disables alignment
tried table but creates spaces between images

I expect, no spaces between images, so it looks as if it was one picture.
Also please I expect to be centered, and to fit 100% in all mobile devices.

Comment: please try to recreate your problem in a fiddle rather than posting random links in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code :

for class:

.content-3 and .content-4

change property:
display: block;
to
display: inline-block

and remove float styles

Here is the codepen:

```
[Link to CodePen][1]
```

Comment: And remove max-width for content-1 and content-2

Answer (score -1):

Change your **HTML** as follows (putting **content3 div** and **content4 div** inside **center-items div**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Poller&iacute;a el Marquez</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content1">
                <img src="http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/img/lptop.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content2">
                <img src="http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/img/lpbtm.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="center-items">
                <div class="content3">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
                        <img src="http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/img/tlf1.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="content4">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
                        <img src="http://www.ojosperuanos.com/marquez/img/tlf2.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Here is the modified CSS classes of **content3** and **content4**, and newly added class **center-items**:

```
.content3 {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

.content4 {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

.center-items{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assist but it isnt centered enough